# How can I add these code completion features my VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm in the process of creating a VSCode extension to do code completion for an existing Lua API.

I'm having a bit of trouble achieving the following (examples are JavaScript):

[image: method information]

[image: parameter information]

I've been looking for examples and tutorials but haven't come up with much. I assume I may need to do a fair amount of string processing, around the current cursor position, to get enough data to lookup the appropriate documentation (which I stored in an array of json objects). But presently I don't know how to get the meta-data dialog to show when entering parameters.

P.S. I have reviewed the official [extension samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your screenshots show two VS Code features:

The first screenshot shows a **hover / quick info**. It is used to display information about the current word the user is hovering over. To add a hover, your extension should implement and register a [`HoverProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#HoverProvider)

The second screenshot shows **parameter hints / signature help**. It displays information to the user as they complete a function call. To add signature help, your extension should implement and register a [`SignatureHelpProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SignatureHelpProvider)

---

In both cases, how you implement the functionality is entirely up to your extension. Most language extensions maintain a structural representation of the file (such as an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)) and use this to provide hover and signature help info.

You can also either implement your extension as a direct VS Code extension or using the language server protocol (which works across editors). See VS Code's [Language Extensions Overview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview) for more information about developing a language extension and why you may want to consider the Language Server Protocol

Comment: Thank you that is exactly the information I needed. Much appreciated.